# Long Polling or WebSockets

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am writing Web chat where you have several one-on-one conversations with people on the screen at the same time. (Basically, like a personal messenger, without group chats).

My technology options seem to be Long Polling and WebSockets, and I'm trying to choose.

The upside with Long Polling is that's it's very easy to implement, and I can return whatever data i want (a customized JSON-object with the data required to update the page).

What I'm afraid of with WebSockets is that there's no native library for it in PHP, so you have to shop between different 3rd party ones, and the concepts seem more complicated, what with channels and subscriptions and what have you.

Browser compatibility is not an issue for me.

1. Is the performance of Long Polling much poorer than with Websockets? If no, then my decision is easy!
2. Is there a really simple Websocket server for PHP? Or is the concept so simple I could write my own? (Mozilla has a really simple [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) on writing a client, but not on a server).

Comment: nginx has web socket support. Install that one and use it to pass data to your php scripts? The alternative is Node.js, it's pretty easy to get it running and to reply with JSON data. Seeing you're talking about JSON, I assume you're familiar with javascript to the point where you could use Node effectively. As for actual server written in PHP - it's just way too much trouble, trust me on that one.

Comment: @N.B.: I already use nginx. So using the nginx Websocket support eliminates the need for a socket server? I just use nginx configuration to pass the data to the right place? Sounds too good to be true if it this is the case. I'd like to hear about the performance aspect too.

Comment: Why not use an existing server and just write the front end ?

Comment: @forthrin from what they wrote at nginx website, it supports that protocol therefore it is a web socket server. I haven't tried it. On the other hand, you can write your own server in PHP. It's just a simple socket listening on a port which has to pass a challenge. PHPWebsocket has it all, you could use that for your base and adjust it. And there's Node.js which makes using websockets really easy if you are proficient with js.

Comment: See [Understanding Realtime PHP Web Apps](http://webandphp.com/UnderstandingRealtimePHPApps-166085)

Comment: @N.B.: Do you know where I can find a minimal working code example with a JavaScript client, relevant nginx configuration and PHP (preferably) server?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your long-polling scheme involves an endpoint hosted by the same web server as your frontend, this will mean two active connections for every user of the application, so you will basically cut the number of users you can support in half. Your websocket server would run on a different port and can bypass your web server, so the connections are a lot of saved overhead with websockets.

Another place websockets save on overhead is that once your connection is established, there is no need for constant requests and responses. Zombie websocket connections are essentially free in terms of both bandwidth and CPU.

Finally, I would not think that long polling would be simpler to implement. Since websockets are designed to do exactly what you want, I think that leveraging an existing websocket package will actually save you some lines of code. I would look at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (feature-rich) or [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) (lite), if you want to use PHP.

Comment: I tried phpwebsocket, but server.php is not receiving "Sec-WebSocket-Key1" and "Sec-WebSocket-Key2". Do you know how I fix this?